# Steam tries to install some dependencies but fails to find package

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dependencies, steam

I tried to install steam on **Ubuntu 20.04** and steam had tried to install **libgl1-mesa-dri:i386** and **libgl1:i386** but I received these errors.

```
Package libgl1:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package.

This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another package

Package libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.

This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another package
However the following packages replace it:
  libgl1-mesa-dri

E: Package 'libgl1-mesa-dri:i386' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libgl1:i386' has no installation candidate
```

- I already have **libgl1-mesa-dri** and **libgl1** **installed**
- I tried to do sudo apt-get installed --reinstalled **libgl1-mesa-dri** **libgl1** but **failed to download**

Thank you Everyone in advance for your help.

**Edit/Note:** I have already enabled i386 Architecture before installing steam.

Comment: post output of `dpkg -l | grep libgl1`

Comment: When did you last run `sudo apt update`? You may have messed up sources.list. What is the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`?Did you have libgl1-mesa-dri and libgl1 installed for 64 bit *only* before? What is the output of `apt-cache policy libgl1-mesa-dri`?

Answer (score 0):

This has helped me.

```
sudo apt purge steam
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
sudo apt install steam
```

Comment: Thank you for your help I really appreciate it but unfortunately before installing steam I had "sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386" but we still appreciate your help thank you.